# API search tweets "wildcard"

Tags: twitter

I'm using the Twitter API to search for posts: [GET search/tweets](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets)
I do a query in Italian and, to make it work for both the male and the female, I run it twice. example:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=alto&lang=it
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=alta&lang=it
```

(change a letter in q=)
There is no way to combine the two queries into one? example q=alt*

ps: I tried to write q=alt but only found the post with the word " alt ", I would " alt+letter "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way that you can use wildcards.  What you *can* do, however, is run two queries at one.

For example

`?q=alto+OR+alta`

Will find tweets containing one - or both - of the queries.

See - for example - https://twitter.com/search?q=alto%20OR%20alta&src=typd&lang=it